# CPT/Taxonomy/Postname permalink structure makes pagination break

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I've defined this permalink structure
custom-post-type/taxonomy/post-name

It all works like a charm, except when it comes to pagination. When I move to page 2, it loads a post instead of the second page.

So url is:
custom-post-type/taxonomy/page/2
But it changes the url and goes to:
custom-post-type/other-taxonomy/one-post/2

Anyone who knows about permalink structures and pagination?
Hope you can help me out.

---

UPDATE

I have defined these:

Portfolio items base: portfolio

Portfolio categories base: portfolio

I've installed Custom Post Types Permalinks and setted up portfolio url like this:
/%portfolio_entries%/%postname%

If I define it like:

/%portfolio_entries%/%postname%/%page%

Pagination works, but portfolio elements aren't being displayed anymore.

Any idea how can I make %page% optional?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with pagination also, but my pagination everytime redirects to 404. What I did was use standard loop but with pre_get_posts function where I defined additional paramets. Now pagination works perfectly on archive, taxonomy or search template.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: Thanks for the tip Damian. By any chance, do you have your function implementation?

Comment: I use exactly this code https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Include_Custom_Post_Types_in_Search_Results but I change of course CPT names.